# Reference enum instance directly without class in Kotlin

Tags: enums, kotlin

In Kotlin, I'm unable to reference the instances of an enum directly when E is in the same file as the code where I use its instances:

```
enum class E {
    A, B
}
```

What I want to do:

```
val e = A
```

What I can do:

```
val e = E.A
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Yes, this is possible!

In Kotlin, enum instances can be imported like most other things, so assuming enum class E is in the default package, you can just add `import E.*` to the top of the source file that would like to use its instances directly. For example:

```
import E.*
val a = A // now translates to E.A
```

Each instance can also be imported individually, instead of just importing everything in the enum:

```
import E.A
import E.B
//etc...
```

This also works even if the enum is declared in the same file:

```
import E.*
enum class E{A,B}
val a = A
```

Comment: Interesting... So the problem I'm having must be because the enum is in the *same* file as where I want to use it.  I'll update the question to included this restriction.

Comment: The compiler complains when I try your same-file snippet.  It says `Unresolved reference: E`.

Comment: For me, this snippet is valid. You can try it in the online compiler here: https://try.kotlinlang.org - Perhaps your enum isn't declared at the top level of the default package? If enum E is declared in class C of package p for example, you'd need `import p.C.E.*` (even for same-file imports)

Comment: You're right - my import wasn't correct.  Now it works!  Thank you!!

Comment: Observation - in a `.kts` file you don't even need the import.  Only in regular `.kt` files.  Allowing Intellij code-completion to guide the construction of the import allowed me to "find" the enum correctly.